# No luck recovering public key after EIP 155

Tags: raw-transaction, signature, public-key, recovery, encoding

I'm trying to understand Ethereum transaction signing, but for some reason I'm unable to verify the signature.

I have a test account, `0xb2c899884790aa9e256a2d4b2256ca3319e64e32`, its public key is
**`e7ab22c376286ccb0616888217bc41ec31eafb090fb77900a3946e39eb5c7fa374c8d5fe191f8001d287e678567bc8058eb49729780d2ac9090ffccbc506a754`**

I take the following valid transaction:

```
{
  "blockHash": "0x3deebc8e1fe36af7f1268ff077cc086c0653fe6fd67aa200608a7379390365f0",
  "blockNumber": "0x613",
  "from": "0xb2c899884790aa9e256a2d4b2256ca3319e64e32",
  "gas": "0x493e0",
  "gasPrice": "0x0",
  "hash": "0x6831112de9dc553de7bb111591cabe0c79b5af8c6395c1bc5411ca2fda539735",
  "input": "0x760a8c2a",
  "nonce": "0x5",
  "to": "0x78c215f61ed07929e0084233a3e86bc011bea132",
  "transactionIndex": "0x0",
  "value": "0x0",
  "v": "0x14c3",
  "r": "0xbddab1b3292ac1102c470d738640bbf91a56a9bbc99a6fc88250800b2b21e25b",
  "s": "0x1959b4b59d0c8552766294459912862a2ca8a62e0b64eab98a4b5be75e910cec"
}
```

Or in raw form: `f8660580830493e09478c215f61ed07929e0084233a3e86bc011bea1328084760a8c2a8214c3a0bddab1b3292ac1102c470d738640bbf91a56a9bbc99a6fc88250800b2b21e25ba01959b4b59d0c8552766294459912862a2ca8a62e0b64eab98a4b5be75e910cec`

According to [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md), I need to hash all 9 values, replacing `v=chainId (2640)`, `r=0` and `s=0`. So I come up with the following "signing data":

`e60580830493e09478c215f61ed07929e0084233a3e86bc011bea1328084760a8c2a820a508080`

It's "signing hash" is:

`749a36ed5f7c67b1f5eb83a46b0dd6447e9ac050a3f469354fcc4691781a385c`

Which, when fed through `ecrecover`, gives the following public key:

**`f1308d673d1cf8014370fffb43f36d5e866e405b2b5cecb3025bfb98ae47b18e21fa07c66b31423414c38611038c4c35387db8510757f65b7a632a2d48b0276e`**

Which obviously does not match the actual public key.

**What am I doing wrong?**

My test code:

```
var ethutil = require('ethereumjs-util');
var raw = Buffer.from('f8660580830493e09478c215f61ed07929e0084233a3e86bc011bea1328084760a8c2a8214c3a0bddab1b3292ac1102c470d738640bbf91a56a9bbc99a6fc88250800b2b21e25ba01959b4b59d0c8552766294459912862a2ca8a62e0b64eab98a4b5be75e910cec','hex');
var data = ethutil.rlp.decode(raw);
var v = ethutil.bufferToInt(data[6]);
var r = data[7];
var s = data[8];
var chainId = Math.floor((v - 35) / 2);
data[6] = ethutil.intToBuffer(chainId);
data[7] = Buffer.from('');
data[8] = Buffer.from('');
var msg = ethutil.rlp.encode(data);
console.log(msg.toString('hex'));
var msgHash = ethutil.sha3(msg);
console.log(msgHash.toString('hex'));
var publicKey = ethutil.ecrecover(msgHash, (v & 1) + 27, r, s);
console.log(publicKey.toString('hex'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the 2nd to last line with:

```
var publicKey = ethutil.ecrecover(msgHash, (v & 1 ^ 1) + 27, r, s);
```

Most of your code looks correct to me but the parity of the 2nd argument to ecrecover must be the same as the parity of the `v` value. So if the  `v` value starts with the value 27, you can go through your calculation and check that your code would set the 2nd argument to 28. That is wrong, and it can be fixed by xoring the value with 1.